# Python exit() command trigger infinite loop

Tags: python, function, loops

Greeting all, I encountered infinite loop when running the code below when input option = 3.

```
def enter_number_only():
    print()
    print("======================")
    print("Enter Number 1-3 only!")
    print("======================")
```

```
def thank_you_goodbye():
    print()
    print("======================")
    print("Thank You & GoodBye!")
    print("======================")
    exit()
```

```
def retry_main_exit():
    while True:
        print("1. Retry")
        print("2. Back to Main Menu")
        print("3. Exit / Quit")
        print("=================================")
        try:
            option = int(input("Please Enter 1 - 3 to Continue: "))
            if option == 1:
                print("1")
                break
            elif option == 2:
                print("2")
                break
            elif option == 3:
                thank_you_goodbye()
                break
            else:
                enter_number_only()
        except:
            enter_number_only()

    return option

retry_main_exit()
```

However, if I replaced:
(initial code)

```
 elif option == 3:
      thank_you_goodbye()
      break
```

to
(edited code)

```
 elif option == 3:
      print("gg")
      break
```

it will exit the loop smoothly.

Need advice on how to remain the initial code but to be able exit the loop? and seeking for the root cause on this issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Updates: The issue get solved by sharing from @Daniel Corin due to `except` clause. The code get fixed with edit below

```
except TypeError:
       enter_number_only()
```

Comment: is the `exit()` function necessary? (in the Thank you goodbye function)

Comment: The exit() function is not needed because the 'break' exits the while loop, and the application ends.If you insist on using an exit\, use sys.exit().

Comment: Why would you need `break` after `exit`

Comment: @jeffthechicken exit() function there just to make sure the program get exited after user input option 3.

Comment: **encountered infinite loop when running the code below when input option = 3.** what infinite loop? When I enter **3** it `exit`s so there is no infinite loop.

Comment: @Countour-Integral it triggered retry_main_exit() infinite loop at my side.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `exit` on last line of `thank_you_goodbye` function, then it will work smoothly.

```
def thank_you_goodbye():
    print()
    print("======================")
    print("Thank You & GoodBye!")
    print("======================")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of folks have mentioned a fix by removing `exit()` but let's dive into why you are seeing what you're seeing with a simpler example:

In the following code, we first request user input, then we call `exit()` which [raises `SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit), which is then handled by the bare `except` clause.

Side note: using bare `except` clauses is not recommended. More on that [here](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E722.html).

```py
while True:
  try:
    i = input('input? ')
    exit()
  except:
    print('hey')
```

We might expect after entering the first user input that the program would loop around to ask for user input again after handling `SystemExit` in the `except` clause. However, what happens instead is the following:

```
❯ python3 test.py
input? 1
hey
input? hey
input? hey
input? hey
input? hey
...infinitely
```

However, if `SystemExit` is handled explicitly, the program *also* does something we might not expect -- it actually exits, raising a different exception:

```py
while True:
  try:
    i = input('input? ')
    exit()
  except SystemExit:
    print('hey')
```

```
❯ python3 test.py
input? 1
hey
input? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danielcorin/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    i = input('input? ')
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

It turns out that raising `SystemExit` closes `stdin` (which is needed by the `input` function), even if the program itself doesn't exit. So in our first example, after calling `exit()`, we have a broken `input` function, which raises a `ValueError` on the second-N calls.

Example `exit()` closing `stdin`:

```py
import sys

try:
  print(sys.stdin.isatty())
  exit()
except SystemExit:
  print(sys.stdin.isatty())
```

```
❯ python3 test2.py
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danielcorin/Desktop/test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    exit()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_sitebuiltins.py", line 26, in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danielcorin/Desktop/test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(sys.stdin.isatty())
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

We're still in the while loop, so all exceptions (first `SystemExit` and then `ValueError` repeatedly) are handled by the bare `except` clause, so the result is the program prints forever, until we signal our program externally to terminate it. This behavior is the same exhibited by your program when `exit()` is called in the `thank_you_goodbye` function.

In short, the `exit()` call breaks the `input` function which leads to an infinite loop due to the bare `except` clause.

Comment: This solved my issue! The root cause is the bare except clause. The issue get fixed once the clause added with `except TypeError:`
Thanks mate!